# HTML <template> is empty in Firefox (devtools and after document.importNode())

Tags: html, firefox, web-component, firefox-developer-tools, html5-template

I would like to use html-templates. Using Chrome everything works, but in Firefox the template-element doesn't have any Content... maybe it is just not shown in the Debugger, but when I try to instantiate the Content of the template I also don't get any Content.

This template-element:

```html
...
<body>
    <template>qwertz</template>
</body>
...
```

doesn't have any content (I expect "qwertz") when I inspect the element in the Firefox debugger. Seems pretty simple... but unfortunatly I can't see what I'm missing here...

Comment: That is [the expected behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). "The HTML <template> element is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript." You should not be seeing anything in Chrome either.

Comment: The Debugger in Chrome is showing the content under a node named  #document-fragment

Comment: My bad, I thought you were talking about the rendered DOM.

Comment: I use JavaScript to instantiate the template. I'm able to get the template-element itself, but that doesn't have any Content.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox’s devtools Inspector doesn’t show `template` contents in the main window of its DOM view.

If you want to examine `template` contents in Firefox’s Inspector, you need to:

1. Right-click on the `template` element in the Inspector.
2. Choose **Show DOM Properties**.

Firefox devtools will then show you the Properties pane, where you can explore all the DOM properties of the `template` element.

So there you can then see the `template` contents by looking at the `innerHTML` property, or looking down through the `content` property.

---

[image: DOM view of <template> element]

---

As far as how to instantiate the contents of a template, here’s a simple example:

```js
var templateContent = document.querySelector("template").content,
    templateContentClone = document.importNode(templateContent, true)
document.body.appendChild(templateContentClone)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <template>qwertz</template>
</body>
```

The important part to understand is that if you want to do anything with the template contents, you need to clone/import the contents using [`Document.importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) or [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Comment: I just noticed, that the template's Content is visable (in DOM Properties) if I  remove the polyfill `webcomponents-lite.js`. I wonder why.

Comment: I don’t know why the polyfill would have that effect—but to get an answer to that, you probably want to post a separate question

Comment: The reason was my mistake. I had a custom element with ShadowDOM. And that custom element had a setter and getter for a property called `shadowRoot`. What I didn't knew was, the Polyfill of HTMLElement also has this property so I accidentally overloaded the setter/getter. After removing that, everything worked.